# Which .NET framework version will be used when there are many installed?

Tags: .net, frameworks

If I have multiple versions of the .NET framework installed on a machine, will the newest version be used?

Will a .NET app use a specific version of the framework depending on how it has been programmed?

Answer (score 5):

.NET applications specify via their CLR header what version of the runtime they require in order to run.  The ability to build and run against different versions of .NET is supported in Visual Studio through the [multi-targeting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx) feature.

Comment: How are these CLR header flags set by the programmer?

Comment: @Craig: See the link I provided. The required .NET version is set in the IDE before the binary is built. This multi-targeting ability was introduced in VS2008. For a C# application in VS, you can right-click on the project, select "Properties", and then on the "Application" tab, you can specify what the application's target framework is.

Answer (score 1):

It's a property of each project (csproj).
You can modify it in the "Application" tab, under "Target framework"

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the application it self, the developer choose what is the suitable Framework that he/she wants to program against

[image]

Then, when creating the Setup Project to deploy the application, there is a flag that tells to install that Framework version, if clients does not have it already

[image]

This is valid to any .NET application

We developers tend to think:

> Do I need the new features of the newest framework?

cause this will install new package in the client, and sometimes we really don't need and assuming everyone has Vista / Windows 7, .NET 3.5 is already there, so we go for 3.5